# Определение новой функции JS после загрузки сайта путем изменения кода страницы

Tags: javascript, html, функции

Дано поле для ввода, функция и две кнопки:

```js
function numAlert(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0: alert(0);
    break;
    case 1: alert(1);
    break;
    case 2: alert(2);
    break;
    }
}
```

```html
<input onchange="numAlert(0)">
<button onclick="numAlert(1)">first</button>
<button onclick="numAlert(2)">second</button>
```

`JS` код и `HTML` элементы вставляются вручную после полной загрузки страницы (изменяется код страницы).
Проблема: после редактирования страницы функция `numAlert` остается неопределенной и кнопки не могут её вызвать.
Вопрос: как определить функцию?
Пробовал вписывать код в консоль, в теги `<script>` перед кнопками, в `head`.
Код в дано упрощен, поэтому я не могу три раза продублировать его в каждом `html` элементе.

Comment: _вставляются вручную после полной загрузки страницы (изменяется код страницы)._ - каким именно образом это происходит?

Comment: угу, нужен код, при помощи которого Вы это делаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.write(`<input onchange="numAlert(0)"><button onclick="numAlert(1)">first</button><button onclick="numAlert(2)">second</button>`);

document.write(`<script>function numAlert(x) {
    switch (x) {
      case 0: alert(0);
      break;
      case 1: alert(1);
      break;
      case 2: alert(2);
      break;
      }
  }</script>`);
```

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот... скопировать, вставить в консоль и нажать enter. Но если на странице есть другие элементы, они просто удалятся

**UP**

```js
let func = document.createElement('div');
func.innerHTML = `<input onchange="numAlert(0)"><button onclick="alert(1)">first</button><button onclick="numAlert(2)">second</button>`;

let script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = `
function numAlert(x) {
    switch (x) {
      case 0: alert(0);
      break;
      case 1: alert(1);
      break;
      case 2: alert(2);
      break;
      }
  }`;

document.body.appendChild(func);
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Есть ещё такой вариант, вроде рабочий и не удаляет содержимое страницы

Comment: если документ уже был загружен write затрет старое содержимое...

Comment: @Я же это написал :)

Comment: да, вероятно у меня телефон это не успел понять, когда я начал писать коммент последней части не было

Comment: Использовал второй код. Понять не могу, почему когда через innerHTML, к примеру, вставляешь, то функция не объявляется?

Comment: @Остап Волянюк, так я же через innerHTML объявил )